# In Mockito Flutter how to write a matcher to match Any except specified?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito

To set the context, I am trying to do this in Flutter.

For example,

I have a test that passes, "if I set my mock to say 'no network connection' and expect 'NetworkUnavailable' to result."

Then, I thought to write next test that "if network is available, result could be anything except 'NetworkUnavailable'"

I am struggling to setup an expect matcher for that. Does Mockito has something for this, something like `AnyExcept([matcher])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`isNot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/isNot.html) `Matcher` that you can combine with other `Matcher`s.  So, for example, you should be able to do something like: `expect(valueToTest, isNot(unwantedValue));` or `expect(valueToTest, isNot(isIn([unwantedValue1, unwantedValue2])));`

If that doesn't do quite what you want, you also can use the [`predicate`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/predicate.html) to easily create your own `Matcher` from a boolean function.

(You might not have found these if you were searching the Mockito documentation
because they're part of [`package:matcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/matcher) (normally included as part of `package:test`); they're used for unit tests in general, not just for mocks.)